# Event Receivers not added when installing wsp

Tags: content-type, event-receivers, feature-receiver

I have a set of event receivers for a SharePoint 2010 content type and Library. Previously, these would install and automatically be activated when I ran a script to install the wsp solution.  I dug up a different way of doing this, however, and now they will install appropriately when I run the solution in debug mode in Visual Studio, but they will not install when I run the aforementioned power shell script.  I checked the site and made sure the feature was activated, but after doing that I still did not see the event receivers using SPM.

I was following the guide from [this page](http://sharepointx-men.com/2010/07/09/sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-part-1-create-event-receiver-for-content-types/)

Event Receiver Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiverItemCheckedIn</Name>
      <Type>ItemCheckedIn</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SharePointFeatures.EventReceiver.EventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>1000</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiverItemCheckingIn</Name>
      <Type>ItemCheckingIn</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SharePointFeatures.EventReceiver.EventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>1001</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiverItemUpdated</Name>
      <Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SharePointFeatures.EventReceiver.EventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>1002</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiverItemUpdating</Name>
      <Type>ItemUpdating</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>harePointFeatures.EventReceiver.EventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>1003</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>EventReceiverItemDeleting</Name>
      <Type>ItemDeleting</Type>
      <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
      <Class>SharePointFeatures.EventReceiver.EventReceiver</Class>
      <SequenceNumber>1004</SequenceNumber>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Feature template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Properties>
    <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true"/>
    <Property Key="AssemblyQualifiedName" Value="$SharePoint.Type.800d2e40-4c00-4517-9ff4-d11da11b6826.AssemblyQualifiedName$"/>
    <Property Key="AssemblyFullName" Value="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"/>
  </Properties>
</Feature>
```

Feature Receiver code:

```
[Guid("fbe26e13-dba2-4fe6-b947-9f2c34accd39")]
public class FeaturesEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{
    private string EventReceiverClassName;
    private string AssemblyFullName;
    /// <summary>
    /// Feature activated logic
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

        try
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;

            //di-associate EventReceiver from Print only content type
            SetAssemblyParams(properties.Feature.Properties);
            DisableEventReceiver(web);


            //associate EventReceiver to content type as defined in configuration <activefields sharepointcontenttypename="Print Only"> 
                FmiMetadataMappingHandler mappingHandler = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", web.Site.WebApplication.Name).GetSection(Utils.GetConfigSectionNameForWeb(web)) as FmiMetadataMappingHandler;
                SPContentType ct = web.ContentTypes[mappingHandler.ActiveFields.SharepointContentTypeName];

                if (ct != null)
                {
                    SPEventReceiverDefinition def = ct.EventReceivers.Add();
                    def.Name = "EventReceiverItemCheckingIn";
                    def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemCheckingIn;
                    def.SequenceNumber = 1000;
                    def.Assembly = AssemblyFullName;
                    def.Class = EventReceiverClassName;
                    def.Update();

                    // bind event receiver to ItemCheckedIn Event                                      
                    def = ct.EventReceivers.Add();
                    def.Name = "EventReceiverItemCheckedIn";
                    def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemCheckedIn;
                    def.SequenceNumber = 1001;
                    def.Assembly = AssemblyFullName;
                    def.Class = EventReceiverClassName;
                    def.Update();

                    // bind event receiver to ItemUpdated Event                                      
                    def = ct.EventReceivers.Add();
                    def.Name = "EventReceiverItemUpdated";
                    def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdated;
                    def.SequenceNumber = 1002;
                    def.Assembly = AssemblyFullName;
                    def.Class = EventReceiverClassName;
                    def.Update();

                    // bind event receiver to ItemUpdating Event                                      
                    def = ct.EventReceivers.Add();
                    def.Name = "EventReceiverItemUpdating";
                    def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdating;
                    def.SequenceNumber = 1003;
                    def.Assembly = AssemblyFullName;
                    def.Class = EventReceiverClassName;
                    def.Update();

                    // bind event receiver to ItemDeleting Event                                      
                    def = ct.EventReceivers.Add();
                    def.Name = "CWTEventReceiverItemDeleting";
                    def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemDeleting;
                    def.SequenceNumber = 1004;
                    def.Assembly = AssemblyFullName;
                    def.Class = EventReceiverClassName;
                    def.Update();
                    //update content type with event receiver
                    ct.Update(true);

                    Utils.LogMessage("CWT Feature Event Receivers added successfully.");
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.LogError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }

    private void SetAssemblyParams(SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties)
    {
        EventReceiverClassName = properties["AssemblyQualifiedName"].Value;
        AssemblyFullName = properties["AssemblyFullName"].Value;
    }// end SetAssemblyParams

    /// <summary>
    /// feature deactivating
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="properties"></param>
    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SetAssemblyParams(properties.Feature.Properties);
        DisableEventReceiver(properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  di-associate event receiver from content type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    private void DisableEventReceiver(SPWeb web)
    {
        try
        {
            FmiMetadataMappingHandler mappingHandler = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/", web.Site.WebApplication.Name).GetSection(Utils.GetConfigSectionNameForWeb(web)) as FmiMetadataMappingHandler;
            SPContentType ct = web.ContentTypes[mappingHandler.ActiveFields.SharepointContentTypeName];
            string errMsg = string.Empty;
            if (ct == null)
            {
                errMsg = string.Format("{0} has not been created in web {1} ", mappingHandler.ActiveFields.SharepointContentTypeName, web.Title);
                Utils.LogError(errMsg);
                throw new Exception(errMsg);

            }
            if (ct != null)
            {
                SPEventReceiverDefinition[] fmiEvents = new SPEventReceiverDefinition[ct.EventReceivers.Count];
                ct.EventReceivers.CopyTo(fmiEvents, 0);

                for (int i = 0; i < fmiEvents.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fmiEvents[i].Class.Equals(EventReceiverClassName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        fmiEvents[i].Delete();
                        Utils.LogError("cwt receiver removed");
                    }
                }


                ct.Update(true);
              //  web.Update();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.LogError(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

*** UPDATE ***

So, now it won't install at all, even in debug mode.  I looked in the logs and the feature is generating an error during the "FeatureActivated" part of the installation.  I commented out all of the code in FeatureActivated and everything except a try/catch in FeatureDeactivating and it still throws this error.

Error message:  `Type names passed to Assembly.GetType() must not specify an assembly.`

Comment: Your 'new' deployment script doesn't happen to involve using 'Update-SPSolution' does it?

Comment: no, it uninstalls and then reinstalls the solution:  Uninstall-SPSolution -> Remove-SPSolution -> Add-SPSolution -> Install-SPSolution, then IISReset, etc.

Comment: You script activates the features as well?

Comment: it apparently always did before.  I didn't change anything with regards to the script.  I did notice the feature wasn't activated so I did activate it later but that still didn't add the event receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure what the problem was, but I made it go away.  Maybe this is the real solution I was looking for, I do not know.  At any rate, I went through the motions commenting out all of my code except for the actual event handler methods themselves.  I then tried running the solution in debug mode.  No dice.  At that point I basically knew it couldn't have been anything I was really doing (it could have but I "knew" it).  So, on a hunch, I rebuilt the solution and packaged it, THEN ran it in debug mode.  Voila.  I then systematically re-added the various code pieces starting with the feature receiver code and everything has been deploying since.  I do, however, continue to package first to prevent my original issue from happening again.  I am not sure that's absolutely necessary but it's easier than running into that same problem again.